# Can we retrieve list data using angularjs in sharepoint 2013 hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, ajax, apps-development, angularjs

I want to retrieve list data by making http calls through angularjs. Is it possible following is my code in Visual Studio for sharepoint hosted app,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>



<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />

<!-- Add your CSS styles to the following file -->
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/App.css" />

<!-- Add your JavaScript to the following file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
```

//*****************************SharePoint App Code***************************************************************************//

```
    var hostweburl;
    var appweburl;

    // Load the required SharePoint libraries
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Get the URI decoded URLs.
        hostweburl =
            decodeURIComponent(
                getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
        );
        appweburl =
            decodeURIComponent(
                getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl")
        );

    });

    var myAngApp = angular.module('SharePointAngApp', []);

    myAngApp.controller('spCustomerController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('Customers')/items" +
                    "?@target='" + hostweburl + "'" +
                    "&$select=CustomerID,CustomerName,CustomerAddress,CustomerState,CustomerCountry",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("success");
            $scope.customers = data.d.results;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("fail");
        });
    });

    /*  myAngApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];       

    }); */


    // Function to retrieve a query string value.
    // For production purposes you may want to use
    //  a library to handle the query string.
    function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
        var params =
            document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
        var strParams = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
            var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
            if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
                return singleParam[1];
        }
    }

//***************************************************************************************************************************//

</script>
```

<%-- The markup in the following Content element will be placed in the TitleArea of the page --%>

    Page Title

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the  of the page --%>

```
<div>
    <p id="message">
        <!-- The following content will be replaced with the user name when you run the app - see App.js -->
        initializing...
    </p>
</div><br />
```

Title
                Employee
                Company

```
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
            <td>{{customer.Title}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.Employee}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.Company}}</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use AngularJS with REST calls in SharePoint hosted apps, as illustrated [here](http://www.jeremythake.com/2013/10/sharepoint-hosted-app-with-rest-angularjs-for-mvc-javascript/).

You should create you own service beside the controller, and rely on promisses.

For example, the service can be:

```
myAngApp.service('spCustomerService', function ($q, $http) {
    this.getCustomers = function ($scope) {
        var appWebUrl =
                 decodeURIComponent(
                     getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl")
             );
        var url = appWebUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Customers')/items?&$select=Title,CustomerID,CustomerName,CustomerAddress,CustomerState,CustomerCountry";
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
        });
    };
});
```

and the controller:

```
function spCustomerController($scope, spCustomerService)
   var promise = spCustomerService.getCustomers($scope);
    promise.then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.customers = [];
        angular.forEach(data.data.d.results, function (customer) {
            $scope.customers.push({
                Title: customer.Title,
                Employee: customer.CustomerID, // I don't know which field you need here
                Company: customer.CustomerCountry
            });
        });
    }, function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error " + status);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks pholpar, the issue is resolved as I was initiating the variable's inside the document.ready those were getting null. As I initiated them outside the function it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
```

Instead of,

var hostweburl;
    var appweburl;

```
// Load the required SharePoint libraries
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Get the URI decoded URLs.
    hostweburl =
        decodeURIComponent(
            getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
    );
    appweburl =
        decodeURIComponent(
            getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl")
    );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link to solve the problem. It mentions manipulation with SharePoint list with angular js and ng grid.

https://codeplayandlearn.wordpress.com/2015/07/02/manipulation-with-sharepoint-list-with-flavored-of-angularjs-and-ng-grid/